# Logic Pro Environment: Panning Signal Processing

Tags: sound-design, panning, signal-processing, transformers, logic-pro

I'm trying to send an arpeggiated audio signal (in logic pro 9) into separate signal streams to creating an automated, synchronised panning effect, in one stereo channel.

Problem 1:
The audio signal being sent to the last touched fader (knob) of the two, which prevents the 'ping pong' pan, despite the monitors below displaying otherwise.

Problem 2:
Although the monitor displays the alternating signal, the output that is sent to only one fader and plays **all** notes at the described pan output, as if arpeggiation had failed.

So far, I have attempted to achieve this using a transformer with an alternating split setting --> Displayed divided audio correctly in monitors, however, the audio does not follow suit.

I am also concerned about note off signals and how they would affect my alternating signal.

The fader knobs outputs in the inspector are assigned to "-1: 10", (This is continuous controller for those unfamiliar with logic pro), for panning. The channel is stereo, the Logic instrument, "Sculpture", is in keyboard mode Poly, with 8 voices. The output of the fader knobs lead to the software instrument.

Here is an image of my current environment attempt:
 [image: Logic Pro Environment Panning Problem]
If any further information is required, I will happily provide it.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the way arpeggiated instruments in Logic work, it's a little problematic to execute tasks that can be seen as rather adventurous. Although it may be seen as a short cut, one of the things I would suggest doing, and would do myself, is bounce the track down once you're happy with the overall sound of it. It'll be much easier to do what you want to do using audio instead of MIDI. I do use Logic myself, and am currently taking a break from scoring a short film.

My honest advice would be to bounce down the audio, although be prepared to do this three or four times in case you're not happy with the sound or want to re-visit the patch you're using in Sculpture. I gave up with Logic's Environment in order to use arps and bought myself a copy of Sylenth1. For atmospherics and pad sounds, I'll often turn to Camel Audio's Alchemy. Sculpture is wonderful for the low down, gurgly horror drones.

I haven't really answered your problem, but I hope this solution might come in handy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't help you with the route you are following.

But! I have ideas for a non-Environment, more low tech way to get that kind of effect. If I were trying to create this kind of effect, I would double the instrument track, and then use two different instances of Logic's Tremolo effect, with offset phase.

Sometimes I'll also double a midi region in two hard panned tracks. And then stagger one of them by 1/16 or 1/8 or 1/4. This can give a nice effect.

Good luck!